# Create "Pull Request" in Sourcetree for Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, atlassian-sourcetree

I tried to create `pull request` in Sourcetree,
but it asked me to set Remote Project Configuration.
In the remote setting there is only 3 host types for this: Bitbucket, GitHub, Bitbucker Server.
there is no option for Azure DevOps

Is there is a solution for this?

[image]

Comment: I got it's! I added by mistake local repository instead remote.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have an old version - that explains why the AzureDevOps option is missing.

[image]

UPDATE: Try adding a local repository instead remote

Comment: I installed Sourcetree just yesterday, and have the latest version - 3.4.9

Comment: ok, I got it's! I add local repository instead remote